# Is the class of power-associative algebras finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A power-associative algebra is a magma $(M, *)$ where the subalgebra generated by any element is associative. This can obviously be axiomatized by an infinite set of equational identities. Can it also be finitely axiomatized in first-order logic, preferably with only equational identities? I asked this question a while ago, in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372252/is-power-associativity-finitely-axiomatizable), but I didn't receive a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You wrote "I asked this question a while ago, but I didn't receive a satisfactory answer." Please include a link to this previous question, even if it's been deleted.

Comment: I do not know what "finitely axiomatizable" means, but if you mean "finite amount of relations", then for a field of $char=0$ the answer is positive. The general case, I believe, is an open problem. I will look for a reference.

Comment: Don't re-ask questions, even if you didn't get a good answer.  Instead, if you want to call more attention to a question, you can offer a bounty.